# How to hide overflowed content in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a container with width `200` and height `100`. Now how do I hide the overflowed content?

I tried using `ClipRect` and `SizedOverflowBox` inside `Container`. None of them work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('A draggable card!'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        child: SizedOverflowBox(
          size: Size(200, 100),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `SingleChildScrollView` or even better `ListView.builder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Column use `ListView` or wrap the column inside a `SingleChildScrollView`

**Example**

````
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        child: SizedOverflowBox(
          size: Size(200, 100),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World"),
              Text("Hello World")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),```
````

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted it to be scrollable but rather for overflowing contents to be hidden.